# accessing child components data in other component's array in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, pagination, pipe

I'm trying to set the 5 in Array(5) to another variable in this code:

What I'm trying to do:

```
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() page: number;

  active = 0;

  pages;

  constructor() {
    this.pages = Array(this.page) //rather than Array(5) 
      .fill(0)
      .map((x, i) => i);
    this.pages.pop();
  }

  get currentPage() {
    return this.active;
  }
}
```

Here's the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/pipe-pagination-tables-vs1mzt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fpagination.pipe.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, I'm not sure of what you're trying to do here, but have a look at [this fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/pipe-pagination-tables-hknfsv?file=src/app/hello.component.ts) of your StackBlitz demo.

Is this what you want to do?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is the page number div should not appear if that page is empty, so, if there's nothing to show on page 4, it shouldnt be there.

Comment: I can do it by changing to Array(4) but I want it to take (Heros.length/3) than simply hard coding it as 4

Comment: @user2709 Then check `hello.component.ts` and `app.component.html` in the provided link. You need to provide the correct input. Btw doing `heros.length/3` doesn't display anything, so you should recheck your paging calculations.